# Pixels to PDF coordinates?

Tags: javascript, pdf, coordinates

How can I find PDF element coordinates using html? I've built a html page that shows a pdf (iframe) and I want to use the mouse-position to find x,y coordinates on the pdf? is that possible?

Here is my current procedure:

1. Converting an existing PDF file into PNG using `ImageMagic` while specifying a
   `density` of 300 DPI.
2. Displaying the PNG as a background image while giving the user an option to create rectangles on that image [new divs]
3. Saving each div's coordinates [top/left] to the database
4. Creating a PDF while using the original PDF as a template using `FPDI and TCPDF` and applying these coordinates to the PDF, but they are positioned badly and not directly on the PDF.

I know that my saved positions are in `pixels` while the PDF library uses `millimeters`  but even when I do the conversion the rectangles are positioned badly.

Comment: Which library are you using to show PDF in your html page ?

Comment: I'm not, i'm converting the PDF to PNG via `ImageMagic convert` (300DPI) and then drawing on that PNG. later on I am using `FPDF` to generate a PDF but the coordinates are not aligning correctly.

Comment: During the conversion to PNG you drop necessary information for conversion. E.g. the origin of the PDF page coordinate system can be anywhere; it *often* is in the lower left corner of the media box but often enough it is not. Furthermore a unit in the default PDF user space corresponds to 1/72 in but that can also be changed on a per page base.

Comment: I've just updated my question

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post a minimal example snippet?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @AshwinSurajbali I've converted the PDF to PNG, placed it as a background of a div and then sampled the coordinates that I wanted

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you can use the `pdfinfo` tool available on *nix systems, you can determine the size of the PDF file in points

```
$ pdfinfo a.pdf
Creator:        Writer
Producer:       LibreOffice 5.1
CreationDate:   Tue Jan 23 19:45:15 2018
Tagged:         no
UserProperties: no
Suspects:       no
Form:           none
JavaScript:     no
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      595 x 842 pts (A4)
Page rot:       0
File size:      36740 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.4
```

A PDF of size WxH would render to `(W * 300 / 72)px x (H * 300 / 72)px` at 300DPI. So the example above renders to `2479px x 3508px` PNG at 300DPI. **Remember: The pixels are rounded to the nearest integer if the calculation results in decimals** A single pixel here and there should not affect your final output anyway.

As to where the 72 comes from, go through: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5859/all-pdfs-appear-to-be-72-dpi-no-matter-what

Finding the mouse position relative to the iframe should be an easy task. I am not answering that part because the question is only for the conversion.

Comment: Ironically, `convert` (ImageMagick) is about 10x slower than exporting the same PDF file via GIMP.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, you use an PNG image in your html to show an image but not the pdf directly...  in that case the best method will be to use an html canva div then using something like [this](https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-mouse-coordinates/) to get the mouse coordinates.

---

Assuming, that left and top margin inside your pdf are and stay constants, you need then to compare the pdf size and the image size manually in the first time, then you may use a javascript function to convert the "*mouse position inside the canva*" to "*the expected position in the pdf file*", but in my opinion it is absolutely not the best method.

---

Why not using [viewerjs](http://viewerjs.org/) or [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/) to show PDF directly in the html page ? (instead of converting your PDF to image then showing an image file)

Comment: Because I want to draw rectangles on the PDF and AFAIK viewerjs or pdf.js can't support it.

mouse position is specified in pixels while PDF position is specified in MM...I tried converting it but the outcome doesnt match.

Answer (score 0):

I did this before.  Can't offer you any code, but generally, the approach I used was to use math formulas to make it all work.

For example, let's say you have a pdf rectangle with top = 100 and left = 200. If the page is an 8.5" x 11" page, and if my viewport is 10 inches wide, I can convert left for the rectangle as follows:

10 / 8.5 * pdf.left

Answer (score 0):

You can set the iframe position absolute, then take x,y mouse pos - iframe pos to translate coordinates for origin at PDF top left. I hope that helps! If there is scrolling you will need to add that to the coordinate on the axis scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your pdf page units, TCPDF already have the method

```
$pdf = new Fpdi(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->setPageUnit('px');
```

This should solve your problem

Answer (score -1):

I think this will help.

HTML

```
<div id="DIV" ></div>
<iframe id="IFRAME">

</iframe>
```

CSS

```
* {
  padding: 0:
  margin: 0;
  }
#DIV {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
}
#IFRAME {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

Javascript

```
(function() {
    var iframepos = $("#IFRAME").position();

    $('#IFRAME').contents().find('html').on('mousemove', function (e) { 
        var x = e.clientX + iframepos.left; 
        var y = e.clientY + iframepos.top;
        console.log('In Side IFRAME');
        console.log(x + " / " + y);
    });
        document.onmousemove = handleMouseMove;
        function handleMouseMove(event) {
            var dot, eventDoc, doc, body, pageX, pageY;

            event = event || window.event; // IE-ism

            // If pageX/Y aren't available and clientX/Y are,
            // calculate pageX/Y - logic taken from jQuery.
            // (This is to support old IE)
            if (event.pageX == null && event.clientX != null) {
                eventDoc = (event.target && event.target.ownerDocument) || document;
                doc = eventDoc.documentElement;
                body = eventDoc.body;

                event.pageX = event.clientX +
                  (doc && doc.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0) -
                  (doc && doc.clientLeft || body && body.clientLeft || 0);
                event.pageY = event.clientY +
                  (doc && doc.scrollTop  || body && body.scrollTop  || 0) -
                  (doc && doc.clientTop  || body && body.clientTop  || 0);
            }

            console.log(event.pageX + " / " + event.pageY);
            elementMouseIsOver = document.elementFromPoint(event.pageX, event.pageY);
            if(elementMouseIsOver){
                var theelement  = $("#"+elementMouseIsOver.id);

              if(elementMouseIsOver.tagName!= "HTML"){
                var offset = theelement.offset();
                console.log("element id : " + elementMouseIsOver.id);
                console.log("on element");
                console.log((event.pageX -  offset.left) + " / " + (event.pageY - offset.top));
              }
            }
        }
    })();
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f53rpt2o/)